How to prove two non-isomorphic strongly regular graphs are not Seidel switching isomorphic?
It is known that $L(K_{4,4})$ and the Shrikhande graph are two non-isomorphic strongly regular graphs but they are Seidel switching isomorphic.(Cvetknvic-Rowlinson-Simic An Introduction to the Theory of Graph Spectra, Example 1.2.4, page 10).
According to https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/srg/srgtab1-50.html, there exist 15 non-isomorphic SRGs with spectrum $\{12,2^{12},-3^{12}\}$. Is it true that any two of these graphs are not Seidel switching isomorphic? How to verify it quickly? Is there any sufficient condition for two non-isomorphic strongly regular graphs not to be Seidel switching isomorphic?
Definition:  Let $U$ be a subset of $V(G)$. The Seidel switching of $G$ with respect to $U$ is the graph obtained from $G$ by  erasing the existing edges and adding the nonexisting ones between $U$ and its complement $\overline{U}$.
